# Tweening in as3 stopping the next tween to happen until the last one is finished

Tags: actionscript-3

How to stop the next tween action to start until the previous tween completes playing in as3.0?

and also i want to stop the tween to happen on the same object twice.

Basically i have a container (movie-clip) in which there are n number of movie-clips (arranged as bricks). When i click on the container the target (brick) will disappear (made scaleX and alpha to 'o'). also i am tracking how many bricks are closed.

But the problem is if i do a fast double click the tween seems to happen twice. and the count also seems to increase for the same brick. how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Tween after Tween**

Use an event handler to wait for the first tween to complete, Something like

```
myTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);

function onFinish(e:TweenEvent):void {

         ... // Call the next tween here

}
```

---

**Double click problem**,

Remove the event listener for the button click as soon as it is clicked, Something like:

```
my_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent){

        my_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

        myTween.start();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Tweener](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/) and use

`isTweening()` or `autoOverwrite = false` to get around this.

I haven't used those properties/functions in a while but I'm sure something in Tweener can do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you are using Tweener. Greensock's Tweenmax/lite package is seemingly the industry standard these days.

The problem you seem to be having is that you are initiating the tween multiple times. If all the blocks need to shrink simultaneously, i would probably use a for loop and run a tween on each of them.

The thing you have to make sure though is once its clicked to remove the click event handler until its complete so it won't be clicked again.

I also would recommend using TweenMax/Lite because it has something called TimelineMax/Lite where you can compound a bunch of tween be it simultaneous or staggered and listen for one COMPLETE event on that Timeline object. When that event fires you can reactivate the clicks or do whatever it is you need to do after the animation is complete.

TimelineMax has some nice features as well like reverse and timeScale.

would you be able to paste some code? that would also help us help you.